# Bootstrap 3.3.6 - Placing button in footer nav results in idented button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use a footer/bottom nav, and place a button instead of the "brand"

however, the button is not left justified (compared to text brand) , but is slightly indented.

```
      <footer>
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
                                      <div class="container-fluid">
                                                    <div class="navbar-header">
                                                        <li class="dropup">
                                                             <!--   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">wybierz region<b class="caret"></b></a> -->
                                                               <button type="button" class="navbar-brand btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-left: 40px;">
                                                              <i class="fa fa-globe" style="color:green"></i> Language: English<span class="caret"></span>
                                                              </button>
                                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu columns">
                                                                    <li><a href="#"><strong>English</strong></a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">Français</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">Deutsch</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">Español</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">עברית</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">العربية</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">Italiano</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">Русский</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">Türk</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">Magyar</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">中文</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">日本語</a></li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                              </li>

                                                </div>                                              
                                      </div>
                            </nav>

    </footer>
```

I'm wondering what could be causing this, and if there's a *bootstrapeeze* way of resolving this issue

suggestions are appreciated

Comment: It's not totally clear what you mean given you have `style="margin-left: 40px;"` applied to the button all ready. And will there be other elements inside the navbar or just this button?

Comment: Dang! 
I must be blind.  you nailed it !   (I didn't realize i had the "margin left" there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just use padding-left: 0px in div with class="container-fluid" and style in button should be 0px for margin left**

```
  <footer>
                                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
                                          <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                                        <div class="navbar-header" >
                                                            <li class="dropup ">
                                                                 <!--   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">wybierz region<b class="caret"></b></a> -->
                                                                   <button type="button" class="navbar-brand bg-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-left:0px;">
                                                                  <i class="fa fa-globe" style="color:green"></i> Language: English<span class="caret"></span>
                                                                  </button>
                                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu columns">
                                                                        <li><a href="#"><strong>English</strong></a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">Français</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">Deutsch</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">Español</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">עברית</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">العربية</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">Italiano</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">Русский</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">Türk</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">Magyar</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">中文</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="#">日本語</a></li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                  </li>

                                                    </div>                                              
                                          </div>
                                </nav>

        </footer>
```